# Is it possible to make only the site collection admins be able to add a webpart to a page

Tags: 2010, permissions

I want a add a web part to my SharePoint site. But I don't want other full control users messing with the web part.

Is it possible to make the "Add Web Part " option only available to the site collection administrators only for that particular web part. ie they should be able to add other web parts to a page but not the particular web part.

Please share your thoughts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done based on web part permission .Usually all the web parts inherit from site collection permission.

Go to Webpart gallery from Site Settings and remove inherit permission for the particular Webpart . So that only Site Collection admins will have permission to that Webpart .This Webpart will not visible to other users.